# Custom Assetic Filter Development - Constantly Cached?

Tags: symfony, filter, assetic

I'm having an issue with my development of a custom assetic filter. I loosely followed the steps in the [blog article found here](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/05/24/symfony2-make-your-own-assetic-filter/) and got things working for the most part. The thing that's causing me hang up is the fact that if I make a change to the `filterLoad` or `filterDump` methods it usually shows up the first time but additional changes won't. It seems like things are getting cached but not in the usual Symfony2 cache directory. This is pretty vague so far so let me know if there's any additional information I can provide.

Example of change:

```
public function filterLoad(AssetInterface $asset)
{
    $asset->setContent('this');
}

public function filterDump(AssetInterface $asset)
{

    $asset->setContent('that');
}
```

Comment: The only way I've gotten around this is by editing the file so the cache gets refreshed.